# Are Iterables.filter and Collections2.filter lazy executed?

Tags: java, collections, filter, guava

I try to filter all elements of type `AddReport`

but when putting a breakpoint in the Predicate body, I see the code there is not executed.

Is it lazy? I see all kind of sub-classes.

Not just `AddReport`

```
    Iterable<BaseClass> filtered =
            Iterables.filter(myList,
                    new Predicate<BaseClass>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean apply(@Nullable BaseClass input) {
                            AddReport addReport = (AddReport) input;
                            return ((addReport != null) && addReport.description.equals(messageBody));
                        }
                    });

    Collection<BaseClass> filtered2
            = Collections2.filter(myList,
            new Predicate<BaseClass>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(@Nullable BaseClass input) {
                    AddReport addReport = (AddReport) input;
                    return ((addReport != null) && addReport.description.equals(messageBody));
                }
            });
```

Comment: "Why [...] filtering doesn't work?" What tells you it doesn't work? Have you at least tried to use the produced `Iterable` or `Collection`? It may very well be that evaluation is indeed lazy. But "guava" and "doesn't work" is a contradiction.

Comment: I wrote: "I see all kind of sub-classes."

Comment: Yes, [operations in `Iterables` are lazy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html): _"Unless otherwise noted, all of the iterables produced in this class are lazy, which means that their iterators only advance the backing iteration when absolutely necessary."_; [FunctionalExplained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Predicates) wiki page: _"All Guava filter methods return views."_ Copy elements of your results to some list or do a simple for-each loop and print them to see computed result.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. What do you mean by "I see all kind of sub-classes"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like maybe what you want here is to first filter your iterable to only instances of `AddReport`, which you'd do like this:

```
Iterable<AddReport> addReports = Iterables.filter(myList, AddReport.class);
```